# Display products in a page with a product attribute filter

Tags: woocommerce

On WooCommerce, I want to create a custom page/article that displays all the products that have an attribute with a specific value.
I need a custom page to index it with Yoast SEO and to insert an header on the page, before the product list.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can use [WooCommerce shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#content-product-attributes) like `[products attribute="color" terms="blue" columns="4" limit="12" paginate="true" orderby="title"]` or you can also use WooCommerce Guntenberg Blocks (even better) in your page. Note that we expect you to first make a real search and then provide a real code attempt in your question. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply!
I've found a solution that works, by creating an archive page for the attribute. The reply was also useful, thanks